# Superpowered play from input stream

Tags: superpowered

I wanted to know if superpowered sdk supports playing from a input stream or byte array. I am trying getting bytes from a socket. I know that there is a process method which takes a buffer but I was hoping to have a bytestream from which superpowered gets audio that should be played

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer class or the SuperpoweredDecoder class, then the answer is no.
But if you have a raw PCM audio byte stream, you can just copy it to the buffers of the audio I/O and it will "play".

Comment: No I cannot provide PCM audio byte stream. I have raw mp3 file bytes. You have implemented HLS and I am curious about the way how you handle streaming. So your decoder requires a complete mp3 file to work?

Comment: No, it can use the mp3 frames from memory. We didn't provide a public memory buffer read API option for the decoder.

Comment: @GaborSzanto Could you please provide some more details how to copy buffers? Any sample code is appreciated. Thanks